# Scale SVG around center with plain javascript

Tags: javascript, svg, scaling

I have a problem maybe understanding well how coordinates work ins SVG.  I have a javascript function that scales an svg graphic such as that:

```
var g = document.getElementById("graph");
var nm = g.getCTM().multiply(k); //k is the scale factor
g.setAttribute("transform", "matrix(" + nm.a + "," + nm.b + "," + nm.c + "," + nm.d + "," + nm.e + "," + nm.f + ")");
```

The point is that after scaling the center is slightly translated so the graphic loses is "geographic" center. How can I determine which translation I need to have to scale the graphic "around" its center?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you considered other approaches?

If you just looking for zoom in/out on an svg, it might be easier to do it differently, e.g.:
http://www.cyberz.org/blog/2009/12/08/svgpan-a-javascript-svg-panzoomdrag-library/

I had the same problem a while ago and ended up creating my own zoom using this: https://github.com/rstacruz/jquery.transit

You basically use css transform scale for a svg wrapper and svg adjusts nicely. You can even animate the zooming.

Comment: Thanks for that! Have not heard of jquery.transit before. I am already using SVGPan as is quite good in different ways and found many other complicated utilities that just had to discard. I changed the default code in SVGPan from translate(p.x, p.y).scale(z).translate(-p.x, -p.y) to just scale(z) because it works better, at least in my case, but even with that is not 100% perfect. Anyway I am answering my question as I found a way to scale that convinces me more. Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

As I think fits better my purpose and after reading how to do it in the helpful link

**http://commons.oreilly.com/wiki/index.php/SVG_Essentials/Transforming_the_Coordinate_System#The_scale_Transformation**

I have changed it to scale the graphic *around* the position of the mouse when its wheel is scrolled,

If it helps this is the code (using SVGPan's setCTM method):

```
var svgRoot = document.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0];
var g = svgRoot.getElementById("viewport");

var newp = svgRoot.createSVGPoint();
newp.x = evt.clientX;
newp.y = evt.clientY;
newp = newp.matrixTransform(g.getScreenCTM().inverse());

var oldx = newp.x;
var oldy = newp.y;

//z = scale factor
setCTM(g, g.getCTM().translate(-(oldx*(z-1)),-(oldy*(z-1))).scale(z));
```